# How to prevent xss

Tags: url, xss

this is my native url:

```
127.0.0.1//myweb/home.php?u=daniel
```

now when I include this type of xss:

```
127.0.0.1//myweb/home.php/"><script>alert('hacked')</script>?u=daniel
```

it now appears to be hacked, how can I avoid this type XSS attack ?

**ADDED**

Here is the other codes: (I do not add the fetching the users the data)

```
require_once 'core/init.php';

$currentUser = new User();

$report = null;
if(!$currentUser->isLoggedIn()) {
    Redirect::to('index.php');
}
```

Comment: You have to show the PHP code that is managing this part of your application.

Comment: my code on this page, is only if users is logged it will be pass and if not it will redirect to `index.php` then other codes are for fetching data only. Is that okay ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use php to filter away all the unnecessary part of the url.
This is your web site so you know what character is useless in your web site.

For example, I know that in my web site, the double quotes/" character is useless in my web site.
So, I can straight away filter out any part with double quotes/" character.

You can get your current url from the following code.
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Then, you just ignore anything after double quotes character by using explode.

$safe_url = explode("\"", $url);

So, you will just use $safe_url[0] as your url.

Comment: when I use this script `/"><script>alert('hacked')</script>` after `.php` my website will be appear as attacked this too `>"><script>alert("XSS")</script>&`

Comment: Well, you already know your url is 127.0.0.1//myweb/home.php?u=daniel
Then, you can just explode the .php to get your safe url.
You can get the parameter after ? using $_GET

Comment: Another way to do it is that use post method to send your parameter.
So, you no need to care whatever data after ? character.
You can just explode .php and ignore everything after that.

Comment: uhm, here is what my website need, when someone try to put  atleast `/` after `.php` my webpage will search it, and when the search is false it will redirects to error page saying page not found ?! I am thankful for your responses.